# Rails dynamic params.require(...).permit(...) syntax?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I can do this code:

```
params.require(:something).permit(:param_a,:param_b)
```

And this:

```
params.require(:something).permit(:param_a,:param_c_attributes:[])
```

My problem is that I need to select the permit parameters depending if some parameter exists. So I tried:

```
premit_params = {:param_a,:param_c_attributes:[]}
premit_params = {:param_a,:param_d} if params[:something] && params[:something][:param_d]
params.require(:something).permit(premit_params)
```

But it's not working.

BTW: Using Rails 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `permit` doesn't expect a hash as an argument, but a list of parameters.

Collect your arguments in an array and split that array with the splat operator (`*`) to list or arguments:

```
premit_params = [:param_a, { :param_c_attributes: [] }]
premit_params = [:param_a, :param_d] if params.dig(:something, :param_d)
params.require(:something).permit(*premit_params)
```

Comment: (pssst. it's the `splat` operator)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the parameter you want exits

For Example:

```
if (user_params.has_key?(:name))

end
```

Moreover, parameters are saved in hash so you have different methods you can use to apply your logic
https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html